# Regex for strings that contain only odd clusters of b's with set {a,b}

Tags: regex

This must be valid

```
ababbba
```

This must be invalid

```
bb
```

I only know that this regex ensures odd b's per iteration

```
b(bb)*
```

However my current regex fails when repeated.

```
(a*b(bb)*)*
```

Comment: Why is `bb` valid if you only want odd numbers of `b`s?

Comment: @Turion I wrote that `bb` must be invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the expression `(a*b(bb)*)*` is that the a* can match 0 or more a, so it would match abbb[0 a]b. I think what you want is something like this:

```
^a*b(bb)*(a+b(bb)*)*a*$
```

that would match any number of a, then an odd number of b followed by 0 or more odd numbers of b, as long as there is one or more a in between, then any number of a at the end. I included the start and end terminators because regex coach gives me partial matches without them.